# Foundation tool-tip `without $(document).foundation();` and `modernizr`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to initialize foundation tool-tip without initializing everything (i.e. `$(document).foundation()`) and I am failing in this simple task.

I am wondering (1) How to use `new Foundation.Tooltip` instead (2) do I need `modernizr` because [documentation in foundation website](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tooltip.html) did not mention modernizr as a requirement.

I mentioned  `modernizr` because without that tool-tip would not have any styles nor html inside that would show.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/foundation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.css" />

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome, you <a>link</a> totally use them!">
          Hover me
        </span>
    </div>



    <script id="jsbin-javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            new Foundation.Tooltip($(".has-tip"), {
                allowHtml: true
            });

            // $(document).foundation();
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there something that still needs to be answered that I can add to my response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the second part first: Foundation 6 doesn't require Modernizr (but F5 did) (see: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/37234-modernizr-and-foundation-6) so you can use all of the Foundation 6 components **entirely without** Modernizr.

In your example I think you are mixing *[creating](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#programmatic-use)* a tooltip dynamically:

```
new Foundation.Tooltip($(".has-tip"), {
    allowHtml: true
});
```

With *[initialising](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing)* a tooltip:

```
$(document).foundation(); // initialise ALL Foundation script - usually required by Foundation generally
```

OR

```
$('.has-tip').foundation() // just scripts associated with this element (e.g. tooltips)
```

So to create and then initialise **JUST** the tooltips:

```
new Foundation.Tooltip($(".has-tip"), {
  allowHtml: true
});
$('.has-tip').foundation();
```

For obvious reasons creation must precede initialisation.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/b6eoh2yg/1/

Answer (score 5):

I haven't worked with foundation before so I'm definitely no expert. However, I think I've figured out why your code isn't working.

## Working Code

You can get all the links needed and see an example of working code in the CodePen located here: http://codepen.io/SupposedlySam/pen/ybbYMp.

## What you need to get Foundation Tooltip plugin working

1. Foundation.css
2. Modernizr.js (placed in the `head` tag or below all other scripts before `body` close (via [Foundation's JavaScript Setup Page](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/javascript.html))
3. JQuery.js
4. Foundation.js
5. Foundation.tooltip.js (only needed if not using foundation.min.js which includes all plugins)

## Weird Stuff Not Really Told To You

1. The tooltip will appear at the top-left of the body (at origin 0,0) if there isn't enough space for the height of the word plus the height of the tooltip.
2. If you want your tooltips to stay open when clicking on the word associated to it, a `tabIndex` must be set on the element.
3. If you're extending the options of a Foundation plugin you must initialize each element you want the functionality on individually.
4. You must use `&quot;` instead of double quotes (`"`) in html attributes and they cannot be escaped with a backslash (`\`).

Answer (score 4):

if you do not want to initialise foundation on your entire document, you can initialise it on specifice elements, like :

```
$('.has-tip').foundation();
```

foundation do not depend on modernizer, it works without any problem without modernizer.

and a codepen to a tooltip without calling document.foundation:

https://codepen.io/faw/pen/vmZjzg